# Comment, flag, and delete are not working

Tags: bug, status-completed

I need to delete my answer on Mathoverflow, but the system does not let me. I also cannot add a comment, delete or flag  an answer on any other SE forum. What is happening?

Comment: I am having these issues, along with an inability to upvote/downvote on Quantum Computing and Physics, but not here for some reason.

Comment: I can comment here, for some reason. I did not try to upvote/downvote. Good that I am not the only one with this problem.

Comment: Just checked: I cannot upvote on MO and any other SE forum except this one.

Comment: superuser meta disappeared for a while from the profiles tab on superuser and just became a link to network profile, about five minutes ago. It's come back now though. Some sort of hiccough.

Comment: @ARogueAnt.: Is it related to my question?

Comment: @markvs I've no idea, but if it were some sort of system-wide authentication glitch, then maybe.

Comment: @ARogueAnt.: In any case it does seem to be an issue which affects some (possibly not all) users, and it should be easy to fix by a moderator just like the issue you pointed out to.

Comment: Possibly related to the problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370963/282094

Comment: @Rob: I am not sure the older problem caused the newer one, but this one does look like a Java Script error again.

Comment: I have the same issue, can only interact with posts on Meta. Otherwise, voting/commenting/etc don't work on any other site.

Comment: I am also having this issue on ELL and Av.SE. USA-Central, macOS, Safari (multiple versions). Appears to be an issue with JavaScrip; clicking on intractable-objects the upvote icons and "Add comment" links gives no result or a page (re)load.

Comment: @randomhead: Exactly, clicking on any of   the icons and comment links just reloads. It is the same on my Windows laptop and on my Samsung phone.

Comment: On some posts I can click "Add a comment" and open the box but I can't type; I need to copy-paste into the comment box.

Comment: I can upvote this, but not anything on spanish.stackexchange.com - what's going on?

Comment: Also my upvote from 11 hours ago is recorded under my "votes" tab, but the arrow isn't blue anymore.

Comment: markvs, In [reply to this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370966/comment-flag-and-delete-are-not-workingi/370972#comment1238222_370966) it's definitely JavaScript related, because [if you disable JavaScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7FX9.jpg) very few things work correctly.

Comment: @Rob: I have disabled JavaScript in Chrome and still have the same issues.

Comment: In the JS console/debugger, I have an error at line 5953:210 in `full.en.js`. The error is: **null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("webpack-public-path").innerText')**

Comment: @markvs, [tag:support] is really more for "how do I do X?", "explain X to me", etc. while [tag:bug] is for "X is broken!"

Comment: @bobble: When I posted the question, I was not really sure it was a bug. I just wanted to delete my question on MO. So I added "support".  I guess I do not know something basic because I do not know what does "status-review" tag mean.  It was added by somebody else. Meanwhile the question on MO has been deleted. The other issues which I and others mentioned remain.

Comment: @markvs tags can shift over time, that's fine. The initial post wasn't sure if it was a bug or not, so [tag:support] might have made sense then, but since this has been confirmed to be a bug using just [tag:bug] is more appropriate. To see what [tag:status-review] (or any tag) means, click on it. In this context it means someone on SE's side is probably looking into it.

Comment: The behavior has been fixed for me

Comment: @randomhead: Not for me.  All issues remain,

Comment: This is likely to be the same bug as [I reported yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370955/295232), which means it's solved by clearing the cache of your browser.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Just cleared the cache. Nothing changed.

Comment: Too bad... thanks for trying!

Comment: Now it  works for me too!

Comment: markvs, yes. [That's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370966/comment-flag-and-delete-are-not-working?noredirect=1#comment1238248_370966) what [I said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370966/comment-flag-and-delete-are-not-working?noredirect=1#comment1238248_370966) would happen if [you have broken JavaScript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370966/comment-flag-and-delete-are-not-working?noredirect=1#comment1238221_370966) - that's probes it's related. --- Glad it's now working correctly for you. --- Which is what I said long ago, @Glorfindel

Comment: Clearing cache didn't help for me, either. Comments and dynamic header icons are still broken. Apparently some static servers are still presenting the old file(s).

Comment: @isherwood same, resetting the cache worked for me on mobile, but not on my desktop.

Comment: It's fixed for me in both Firefox and Chrome on Linux.

Comment: @Glorfindel: JavaScript is not disconnected but the cache is cleared now. Thank you!

Comment: Working for Chrome in Ubuntu now.

Comment: Checked on my Samsung phone. It works even though I did not clean the cache there. Meanwhile the q is closed as duplicate.