# Comment, flag, delete, inbox, achievements are still not working in older Chrome versions

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, google-chrome, mobile-chrome

Comment, flag, and delete causes a jump to the top of the page. You also can't press the inbox or achievements button. This applies to all Stack Exchange and meta sites.

I have cleared the cache. It only works on up-to-date browsers (so it is a [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370966/comment-flag-and-delete-are-not-working#) question in that regard, but the fact it is not working on older Chrome versions has not been addressed), but I will not be updating from my may 2018 Chrome desktop and Android versions to the new versions due to horrible UI changes and functionality loss.

Why has it suddenly (as of some time in December, I think 10th December 2021) stopped working on those versions?

Comment: If you're on a May 2018 build of Chrome, then you are before they implemented globalThis which will cause the JavaScript to fail to run. It's only supported in Chrome 71 (December 2018) and higher.

Comment: Related to [We're Migrating our JavaScript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372590/were-migrating-our-javascript)

Comment: @animuson Shouldn't there be some feature detection implemented so as to warn users of older unsupported browsers? Just letting things break seems like a very aggressive stance

Comment: @animuson Ok. I'll check out chrome 71. Thanks for the info. On android I've got version 70 and desktop version 67 so it might not be the end of the world to update. I know they messed up the android tabs page from a stack to a grid layout where you couldnt see the contents of the tab anymore and only made it permanent on version 91 and that was one of the absolute main issues of the many. On desktop unfortunately I think version 71 was when the horrible [square tab design](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/9fjkt8/chromes_new_square_tabs/) came. There might be some fix extension

Comment: Actually I remember a dreadful transient update on, I'm guessing 71 on android, seeing as I immediately had to downdate, but maybe it was already 72 or something by the time I updated, where they added a thick navigation bar at the bottom of the page taking up a large amount of the screen similar to opera android, so I'll have to choose a version before or after that. I also don't like the new full site design on stack exchange sites on profiles where you are viewing the user questions and answers; It's harder to navigate compared to the collapsed list that was and is still on the mobile site

Comment: Related: *[Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208)*

Comment: @animuson it's broken again a few weeks ago on 71, what version is it now?