# Unable to press "post question". Tags are not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions

I wrote a question on Stack Overflow and I’m unable to type down anything in tags. The tags won’t show up or be accepted. The review part isn’t showing up either. The review your question button won’t work either.

Comment: Try refreshing the page

Comment: i did that. anything else?

Comment: [Related (probably)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370966/comment-flag-and-delete-are-not-workingi).

Comment: It is the same issue as here:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370966/comment-flag-and-delete-are-not-workingi

Comment: i dont think so. im unable to post anything on stack overflow. my question wont even go through the "review your question" button

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console in developer tools?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerText')

Comment: This is likely to be the same bug as [I reported yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370955/295232), which means it's solved by clearing the cache of your browser.

Comment: I am marking as completed, as this should have been fixed with the [other related issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370963/51). Please let us know if it is still happening.

Answer (score 5):

Such problems sometimes happen due to buggy JavaScript code stored in the browser's local cache, while already fixed and published on the server.

To solve this, you have to clear that cache, here are two methods:

1. Hold the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key and press <kbd>F5</kbd> while still holding the CTRL key. This should be cross browser.
2. If the above fails, open the browser developer tools (each browser should have its own) and go to "network" tab. In there, you should have "disable cache" checkbox. Tick this and reload the page. Here it is for Chrome browser, for example:
   [image: Disable cache checkbox in developer tools of Chrome]

After the above, if the problem still persists, it's not cache, so edit the bug report to indicate this.