# Stack Overflow is not letting me post anything, and the areas where I would type into are not fully loading

Tags: support, bug

I am trying to post a question on Stack Overflow at the moment, but the area where I type the question into is not fully loading. Typically, like right now, the area should have these elements...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Right now, though, on Stack Overflow, this is what I am seeing...

[image]

No similar questions are appearing, the body formatting stuff isn't appearing, and the tags aren't loading. I switched Wi-Fi networks and browsers, but this is still all broken across not only asking a question, but answering one or trying to comment as well. None of them are working and I cannot post anything. How can I fix this?

I have also tried clearing the cache like suggested in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370970/unable-to-press-post-question-tags-are-not-working), but it is not working.

Comment: There's likely an error in your console that'd probably be useful for the people working on this

Comment: Thanks. It just fixed itself out of nowhere as I pulled up the console after I've been trying for about an hour so I guess it doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: Is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370966/282094) the duplicate, due to the [JavaScript error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370955/282094); fixed by clearing your cache?

Comment: Clearing my cache didn't do it. I tried clearing my cache and I tried other browsers. As soon as I edited this question to include the duplicate, I went back to StackOverflow and reloaded the page and it worked. So I'm not sure what the problem or solution was.

Comment: That does sound like the same problem. That clearing your cache didn't do it initially doesn't really rule it out... cache can be... sticky